# Which matrices preserve range?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Any matrix $M$ has a given range (column space).  Let $B$ be a matrix such that for all $M$, $MB$ has the same column space as $M$.  Clearly, the identity matrix $I$ satisfies this, as does any non-zero scalar multiple of $I$.  Are there other matrices which satisfy this property for all $M$? Is there a name for matrices which satisfy this property? What about $BM$ instead of $MB$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are called matrices of full row  rank.  That is, if $B$ is $m \times n$ (where the number $m$ of rows of $B$ is also the number of columns of $M$ in order for the multiplication $MB$ to be possible), $B$ must have rank $m$.
Of course $n \ge m$ for this to be possible.

As for $BM$ (where this time $B$ must be a square matrix with the same number of columns as $M$ for the question to make sense), in order for $BM$ to always have the same column space as $M$, $B$ must be a nonzero scalar multiple of the identity matrix.